# Strikethrough text based on checkbox

Tags: html, css

Am trying to implement the following: Strikethrough a VAT value in a  based on a checkbox click in another div.

I tried the following HTML and CSS but it didn't work:

```css
.vat-checkbox:checked + .vat-value {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="vat-check"><input type="checkbox" name="vat-check" class="vat-checkbox"> TVA<small>(19%)</small></td>
        <td class="vat-value" id="vat">1 396,500</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can you please advise.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible with pure CSS with **nested elements** (table). You can do it if the elements are on the same level:

```css
.vat-checkbox:checked + span + .vat-value{text-decoration: line-through;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vat-check" class="vat-checkbox"> 
<span>TVA<small>(19%)</small></span>
<span class="vat-value" id="vat">1 396,500</span>
```

For nested elements you can use JavaScript:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('[name="vat-check"]');
const value = document.getElementById('vat');

const handleChange = (e) => {
  e.target.checked 
     ? value.classList.add('checked')
     : value.classList.remove('checked');
}

input.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
```

```css
.vat-value.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="vat-check"><input type="checkbox" name="vat-check" class="vat-checkbox"> TVA<small>(19%)</small></td>
    <td class="vat-value" id="vat">1 396,500</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript, I don't think CSS can achieve what you want if the elements are placed like that.

### You were using Adjacent Sibling Selector

`div + p`
example: Select all `<p>` tags that immediately follows after `<div>` tag

Try the javascript below, using event listener and listen to when the checkbox is clicked then change the style of the vat.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=vat-check]");
  const vat_value = document.getElementById('vat');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (this.checked)
    vat_value.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  else
    vat_value.style.textDecoration = 'none';

});
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
      <label for="vat_checkbox">
        <input id="vat_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vat-check" class="vat-checkbox"> 
        TVA<small>(19%)</small>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td><span id="vat">1 396,500</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it worked fine!  lessons learned :)